# How to update Istio configuration after installation?

Tags: istio

Every document I found only tells you how to enable/disable a feature while installing a new Istio instance. But I think in a lot of cases, people need to update the Istio configuration.

- [Accessing External Services](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/), in this instance, it says I need to provide `<flags-you-used-to-install-Istio>`, but what if I don't know how the instance was installed?
- [Address auto allocation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/dns-proxy/#address-auto-allocation), in this instance, it doesn't mention a way to update the configuration. Does it imply this feature has to be enabled in a fresh installation?

Why there's no `istioctl update` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion totally makes sense. As at least it would be nice for it to be called out somewhere.

Basically, there is no update command for the same reason as there is no `kubectl update` command. What istioctl does is generate the YAML output which represents in a declarative way how your application should be running. And then applies it to the cluster and Kubernetes handles it.

So basically `istioctl install` with the same values will produce the same output and when applied to Kubernetes, if there were no changes, nothing will be updated.

Comment: So, basically I need to remember how I used "istioctl install" last time. What if I do not remember or if someone else used "istioctl install"? Will I override my previous configuration?

Comment: The IstioOperator config is stored in the installation namespace, which you can reuse. However, it's even better if you keep the config you used to install in git so that you can track the changes. Checkout the official docs on how to install using the config which is an IstioOperator: https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/istioctl/#install-istio-using-the-default-profile

Answer (score 0):

I will rephrase your questions to be more precise, I believe the context is the same:

1. How do I find Istio installation configuration

   - Prior to installation, you should have [generated the manifest](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/istioctl/#generate-a-manifest-before-installation). This can be done with

     ```text
     istioctl manifest generate <flags-you-use-to-install-Istio> > $HOME/istio-manifest.yaml
     ```

     With this manifest you can inspect what is being installed, and track changes to the manifest over time.
     This will also capture any changes to underlying charts (if installed with Helm). Just add `-f` flag to the command:

     ```text
     istioctl manifest generate -f path/to/manifest.yaml > $HOME/istio-manifest.yaml
     ```
   - If there is no manifest available, you can check `IstioOperator` CustomResource, but Istio must be installed with operator, for it to be available.
   - If neither of the above are available, you are out of luck. This is not an optimal situation, but it is what we get.
2. How do I customize Istio installation

   - Using [`IstioOperator`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/customize-installation/#customize-kubernetes-settings)
     You can pass new configuration, in YAML format, to `istioctl install`

     ```sh
     echo '
     apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
     kind: IstioOperator
     spec:
       components:
         pilot:
           k8s:
             resources:
               requests:
                 cpu: 1000m # override from default 500m
                 memory: 4096Mi # ... default 2048Mi
             hpaSpec:
               maxReplicas: 10 # ... default 5
               minReplicas: 2  # ... default 1
     ' | istioctl install -f -
     ```

     <sup>*The above example adjusts the resources and horizontal pod autoscaling settings for Pilot*</sup>
   - Any other configuration (`ServiceEntry`, `DestinationRule`, etc.) is deployed like any other resource with `kubectl apply`.
3. Why is there no `istioctl update` command

   Because of the #2. Changes to Istio are applied using `istioctl install`.

   If you want to upgrade Istio to a newer version, there are [instructions](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/upgrade/) available in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Good brother, I registered an account to speak. I have been looking for a long time how to update istio, such as the configuration of the global grid. After seeing your post and the answer below, I finally have an answer.
My previous operation was to create two configurations, one is istiod configuration and the other is ingress configuration. When I perform istioctl install -f istiod.yaml, my ingress will be deleted, which bothers me.
Until I saw this post, I got it
I merged the two files into one, the following is my file, it can be updated without deleting my ingress configuration

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  profile: minimal
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
    accessLogEncoding: TEXT
    enableTracing: true
    defaultConfig:
      tracing:
        zipkin:
          address: jaeger-collector.istio-system:9411
        sampling: 100
  components:
    ingressGateways:
    -name: ingressgateway
      namespace: istio-ingress
      enabled: true
      label:
        # Set a unique label for the gateway. This is required to ensure Gateways
        # can select this workload
        istio: ingressgateway
  values:
    gateways:
      istio-ingressgateway:
        # Enable gateway injection
        injectionTemplate: gateway
```

Thank you very much, this post solved my troubles